# If a creature is blocking and it has vigilance does it still tap?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a creature is blocking and it has vigilance does it still tap?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Unfortunately your question is not quite clear. Which creature has vigilance, the attacker or the blocker? And which creature are you asking about being tapped, attacker or blocker?

Answer (score 10):

Declaring a creature as blocker never taps it, whether it has vigilance or not. Only attacking creatures will be tapped:

> 508.1f The active player taps the chosen creatures. Tapping a creature when it’s declared as an attacker isn’t a cost; attacking simply causes creatures to become tapped.

(of course, Vigilance prevents this:

> 702.20b Attacking doesn’t cause creatures with vigilance to tap. (See rule 508, “Declare Attackers Step.”)

Such a rule is not present for blocking creatures; only that they must be *untapped* in order to block:

> 509.1a The defending player chooses which creatures they control, if any, will block. The chosen creatures must be untapped. For each of the chosen creatures, the defending player chooses one creature for it to block that’s attacking that player or a planeswalker they control.

If a creature with vigilance becomes tapped because of another spell or effect, it won't be able to block.

Comment: Shouldn't we wait for clarification what OP actually wants to know, or what misconceptions he has about combat?

Comment: @Hackworth I assumed the same thing as Glorfindel; while I agree the question could be clearer I think this answer is a reasonable and most likely interpretation of the question.

Comment: It's a common misconception among newer players that creatures also tap to block - I'm not sure where it comes from.

Comment: @xploshun I think its from falsely drawing the parallel between tapping a card and the card performing an action.  As someone who has played a grand total of 1 game (though I've watched friends play a bunch), I can see how you'd go from "tap this creature to make it attack" to "also tap a creature to make it block".  

There might be another source of confusion, but I can see how someone with not much experience trying to extrapolate from some of the rules that they know, and coming to an inaccurate conclusion.

Comment: @xploshun At least in my case that misconception was caused by playing the game "force of will" before starting with magic. It is rather new and in many aspects a lot like magic, but in that game not only attacking but also blocking creatures are tapped.